# Android ExoPlayer not resuming after network is connected

Tags: android, exoplayer

Im using [Exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) for HLS Streaming in my App. Its playing nicely but when i disconnect the internet connection and enable it again,Exo player does not resume the video play.

Exoplayer is handling this by default or do i need to manually handle this?

here is my code..`

```
    public class PlayerActivity extends Activity   implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnClickListener,
    DemoPlayer.Listener, DemoPlayer.CaptionListener,    DemoPlayer.Id3MetadataListener,
    AudioCapabilitiesReceiver.Listener {                                                                    public class PlayerActivity extends Activity   implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnClickListener,
        DemoPlayer.Listener, DemoPlayer.CaptionListener,    DemoPlayer.Id3MetadataListener,
        AudioCapabilitiesReceiver.Listener {

      // For use within demo app code.
      public static final String CONTENT_ID_EXTRA = "content_id";
      public static final String CONTENT_TYPE_EXTRA = "content_type";
      public static final String PROVIDER_EXTRA = "provider";

      // For use when launching the demo app using adb.
      private static final String CONTENT_EXT_EXTRA = "type";

      private static final String TAG = "PlayerActivity";
      private static final int MENU_GROUP_TRACKS = 1;
      private static final int ID_OFFSET = 2;

      private static final CookieManager defaultCookieManager;
      static {
        defaultCookieManager = new CookieManager();
        defaultCookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ORIGINAL_SERVER);
      }

      private EventLogger eventLogger;
      private MediaController mediaController;
      private View debugRootView;
      private View shutterView;
      private AspectRatioFrameLayout videoFrame;
      private SurfaceView surfaceView;
      private TextView debugTextView;
      private TextView playerStateTextView;
      private SubtitleLayout subtitleLayout;
      private Button videoButton;
      private Button audioButton;
      private Button textButton;
      private Button retryButton;
       static TextView bitrateTextView;

      private static DemoPlayer player;
      private DebugTextViewHelper debugViewHelper;
      private boolean playerNeedsPrepare;

      private long playerPosition;
      private boolean enableBackgroundAudio;

      private Uri contentUri;
      private int contentType;
      private String contentId;
      private String provider;

      RotateAnimation rotate;
      ImageView rotateLoad=null;
      ImageView loadMid=null;
      FrameLayout videoLoad;



        private String vidLink ="";
        private String title ="";       private TextView vodTitle;
        private String description =""; private TextView vodDesc;
        private String vodimage ="";    private ImageView vodThumb;
        private String chimage ="";     private ImageView chLogo;
        private String datetitle ="";   private TextView vodTimeDesc, videoCurrentTime, videoTimeEnd;
        private Bitmap vodImgThumb, chImgLogo;
        private static FrameLayout guideInfo;
        private FrameLayout seekBar;
        private FrameLayout playPause;
        private int rewindRate  = 1;
        private int forwardRate = 1, stopPosition ;
        private SeekBar sb;
        CountDownTimer ct;
        int infoFade = 0 , seekFade =0 , height, width;
        private boolean isPlaying = false;
         static long storeBitRate;




    private AudioCapabilitiesReceiver audioCapabilitiesReceiver;

      // Activity lifecycle

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.player_activity);
        View root = findViewById(R.id.root);


        shutterView = findViewById(R.id.shutter);
        debugRootView = findViewById(R.id.controls_root);

        videoFrame = (AspectRatioFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.video_frame);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        debugTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.debug_text_view);

        playerStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player_state_view);
        subtitleLayout = (SubtitleLayout) findViewById(R.id.subtitles);

        mediaController = new KeyCompatibleMediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(root);
      //  retryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retry_button);
      //  retryButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        videoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.video_controls);
        audioButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.audio_controls);
        textButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.text_controls);

         playPause = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoPlayPause);
         videoLoad = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoLoad);

         sb = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
         // Guide Info Animator
         guideInfo = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.guide_info);
         seekBar = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.video_seek);
         playPause = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoPlayPause);
         videoCurrentTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.video_timestart);
         bitrateTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bitratetext);
         videoTimeEnd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.video_timeend);
         seekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         playPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);



          root.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
              if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ESCAPE
                  || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
                return false;
              }
              if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE) {

                  }
              return mediaController.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }


          });






        CookieHandler currentHandler = CookieHandler.getDefault();
        if (currentHandler != defaultCookieManager) {
          CookieHandler.setDefault(defaultCookieManager);
        }

        audioCapabilitiesReceiver = new AudioCapabilitiesReceiver(this, this);
        audioCapabilitiesReceiver.register();
      }

      @Override
      public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        releasePlayer();
        playerPosition = 0;
        setIntent(intent);
      }

      @Override
      public void onResume() {
           super.onResume();
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            contentUri = intent.getData();
            contentType = Util.TYPE_HLS;
            title = extras.getString("title", title);
            description = extras.getString("description", description);
            vodimage = extras.getString("vodimage", vodimage);
            chimage = extras.getString("chimage", chimage);
            datetitle = extras.getString("datetitle", datetitle);


            // Set Data
            vodTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vodTitle);
            vodTitle.setText(title);
            vodDesc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vodDesc);
    /*       DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter(player.getMainHandler(), null);
            String dfg=bandwidthMeter.getBitrateEstimate()+"";*/
            vodDesc.setText(description);
            vodThumb = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.vodThumb);
            chLogo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.chLogo);
            vodTimeDesc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vodTimeDesc);
            vodTimeDesc.setText(datetitle);



            rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotate.setDuration(2000);
            rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

            rotateLoad= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lycaLoadMid_rotate);
            loadMid = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lycaLoadMid);

            rotateLoad.startAnimation(rotate);
            videoLoad = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoLoad);

            //Gathering images 
            LoadImages  loadImage= new LoadImages ();
            loadImage.execute(vodimage,chimage);





            if (player == null) {
             // if (!maybeRequestPermission()) {
                preparePlayer(true);
              //}
            } else {
              player.setBackgrounded(false);
            }



      }

      @Override
      public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (!enableBackgroundAudio) {
          releasePlayer();
        } else {
          player.setBackgrounded(true);
        }
        shutterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        audioCapabilitiesReceiver.unregister();
        releasePlayer();
      }

      // OnClickListener methods

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == retryButton) {
          preparePlayer(true);
        }
      }

      private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
                 = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetworkInfo != null;
        }



      // AudioCapabilitiesReceiver.Listener methods

      @Override
      public void onAudioCapabilitiesChanged(AudioCapabilities audioCapabilities) {
        if (player == null) {
          return;
        }
        boolean backgrounded = player.getBackgrounded();
        boolean playWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
        releasePlayer();
        preparePlayer(playWhenReady);
        player.setBackgrounded(backgrounded);
      }

      // Permission request listener method



      // Internal methods

      private RendererBuilder getRendererBuilder() {
        String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "ExoPlayerDemo");
        switch (contentType) {
          case Util.TYPE_SS:
            return new SmoothStreamingRendererBuilder(this, userAgent, contentUri.toString(),
                new SmoothStreamingTestMediaDrmCallback());
          case Util.TYPE_DASH:
            return new DashRendererBuilder(this, userAgent, contentUri.toString(),
                new WidevineTestMediaDrmCallback(contentId, provider));
          case Util.TYPE_HLS:
            return new HlsRendererBuilder(this, userAgent, contentUri.toString());
          case Util.TYPE_OTHER:
            return new ExtractorRendererBuilder(this, userAgent, contentUri);
          default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported type: " + contentType);
        }
      }

      private void preparePlayer(boolean playWhenReady) {
        if (player == null) {
          player = new DemoPlayer(getRendererBuilder());
          player.addListener(this);
          player.setCaptionListener(this);
          player.setMetadataListener(this);
          player.seekTo(playerPosition);
          playerNeedsPrepare = true;
          mediaController.setMediaPlayer(player.getPlayerControl());
          mediaController.setEnabled(true);
          eventLogger = new EventLogger();
          eventLogger.startSession();
          player.addListener(eventLogger);
          player.setInfoListener(eventLogger);
          player.setInternalErrorListener(eventLogger);
          //debugViewHelper = new DebugTextViewHelper(player, debugTextView);
         // debugViewHelper.start();
        }
        if (playerNeedsPrepare) {
          player.prepare();
          playerNeedsPrepare = false;
          updateButtonVisibilities();
        }
        player.setSurface(surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
        player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);


        guideInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        guideInfo.postDelayed(new Runnable() { public void run() { guideInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE); } }, 5000);





      }



      private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
          debugViewHelper.stop();
          debugViewHelper = null;
          playerPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
          player.release();
          player = null;
          eventLogger.endSession();
          eventLogger = null;
        }
      }

      // DemoPlayer.Listener implementation

      @Override
      public void onStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

          if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {
              showControls();
            }
            if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING) {
                if(videoLoad.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                    videoLoad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

              }
            if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) {
                videoLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }
            if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {
                videoLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finish();
              }
            if(playWhenReady){

            }
        String text = "playWhenReady=" + playWhenReady + ", playbackState=";
        switch(playbackState) {
          case ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING:
            text += "buffering";

            break;
          case ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED:
            text += "ended";
            break;
          case ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE:
            text += "idle";
            break;
          case ExoPlayer.STATE_PREPARING:
            text += "preparing";
            break;
          case ExoPlayer.STATE_READY:
            text += "ready";
            break;
          default:
            text += "unknown";
            break;
        }
       // playerStateTextView.setText(text);
        updateButtonVisibilities();
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Exception e) {                                    
        String errorString = null;
        if (e instanceof UnsupportedDrmException) {
          // Special case DRM failures.
          UnsupportedDrmException unsupportedDrmException = (UnsupportedDrmException) e;
          errorString = getString(Util.SDK_INT < 18 ? R.string.error_drm_not_supported
              : unsupportedDrmException.reason == UnsupportedDrmException.REASON_UNSUPPORTED_SCHEME
              ? R.string.error_drm_unsupported_scheme : R.string.error_drm_unknown);
        } else if (e instanceof ExoPlaybackException
            && e.getCause() instanceof DecoderInitializationException) {
          // Special case for decoder initialization failures.
          DecoderInitializationException decoderInitializationException =
              (DecoderInitializationException) e.getCause();
          if (decoderInitializationException.decoderName == null) {
            if (decoderInitializationException.getCause() instanceof DecoderQueryException) {
              errorString = getString(R.string.error_querying_decoders);
            } else if (decoderInitializationException.secureDecoderRequired) {
              errorString = getString(R.string.error_no_secure_decoder,
                  decoderInitializationException.mimeType);
            } else {
              errorString = getString(R.string.error_no_decoder,
                  decoderInitializationException.mimeType);
            }
          }
          else {
            errorString = getString(R.string.error_instantiating_decoder,
                decoderInitializationException.decoderName);
          }
        }
        if (errorString != null) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        playerNeedsPrepare = true;
        updateButtonVisibilities();
        showControls();
      }

      @Override
      public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int unappliedRotationDegrees,
          float pixelWidthAspectRatio) {
        shutterView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        videoFrame.setAspectRatio(
            height == 0 ? 1 : (width * pixelWidthAspectRatio) / height);
      }

      // User controls

      private void updateButtonVisibilities() {
       // retryButton.setVisibility(playerNeedsPrepare ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        videoButton.setVisibility(haveTracks(DemoPlayer.TYPE_VIDEO) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        audioButton.setVisibility(haveTracks(DemoPlayer.TYPE_AUDIO) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        textButton.setVisibility(haveTracks(DemoPlayer.TYPE_TEXT) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
      }

      private boolean haveTracks(int type) {
        return player != null && player.getTrackCount(type) > 0;
      }

      public void showVideoPopup(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        configurePopupWithTracks(popup, null, DemoPlayer.TYPE_VIDEO);
        popup.show();
      }

      public void showAudioPopup(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        Menu menu = popup.getMenu();
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, R.string.enable_background_audio);
        final MenuItem backgroundAudioItem = menu.findItem(0);
        backgroundAudioItem.setCheckable(true);
        backgroundAudioItem.setChecked(enableBackgroundAudio);
        OnMenuItemClickListener clickListener = new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if (item == backgroundAudioItem) {
              enableBackgroundAudio = !item.isChecked();
              return true;
            }
            return false;
          }
        };
        configurePopupWithTracks(popup, clickListener, DemoPlayer.TYPE_AUDIO);
        popup.show();
      }

      public void showTextPopup(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        configurePopupWithTracks(popup, null, DemoPlayer.TYPE_TEXT);
       popup.show();
      }

      public void showVerboseLogPopup(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        Menu menu = popup.getMenu();
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, R.string.logging_normal);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, R.string.logging_verbose);
        menu.setGroupCheckable(Menu.NONE, true, true);
        menu.findItem((VerboseLogUtil.areAllTagsEnabled()) ? 1 : 0).setChecked(true);
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == 0) {
              VerboseLogUtil.setEnableAllTags(false);
            } else {
              VerboseLogUtil.setEnableAllTags(true);
            }
            return true;
          }
        });
        popup.show();
      }

      private void configurePopupWithTracks(PopupMenu popup,
          final OnMenuItemClickListener customActionClickListener,
          final int trackType) {
        if (player == null) {
          return;
        }
        int trackCount = player.getTrackCount(trackType);
        if (trackCount == 0) {
          return;
        }
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return (customActionClickListener != null
                && customActionClickListener.onMenuItemClick(item))
                || onTrackItemClick(item, trackType);
          }
        });
        Menu menu = popup.getMenu();
        // ID_OFFSET ensures we avoid clashing with Menu.NONE (which equals 0).
        menu.add(MENU_GROUP_TRACKS, DemoPlayer.TRACK_DISABLED + ID_OFFSET, Menu.NONE, R.string.off);
        for (int i = 0; i < trackCount; i++) {
          menu.add(MENU_GROUP_TRACKS, i + ID_OFFSET, Menu.NONE,
              buildTrackName(player.getTrackFormat(trackType, i)));
        }
        menu.setGroupCheckable(MENU_GROUP_TRACKS, true, true);
        menu.findItem(player.getSelectedTrack(trackType) + ID_OFFSET).setChecked(true);
      }

      private static String buildTrackName(MediaFormat format) {
        if (format.adaptive) {
          return "auto";
        }
        String trackName;
        if (MimeTypes.isVideo(format.mimeType)) {
          trackName = joinWithSeparator(joinWithSeparator(buildResolutionString(format),
              buildBitrateString(format)), buildTrackIdString(format));
        } else if (MimeTypes.isAudio(format.mimeType)) {
          trackName = joinWithSeparator(joinWithSeparator(joinWithSeparator(buildLanguageString(format),
              buildAudioPropertyString(format)), buildBitrateString(format)),
              buildTrackIdString(format));
        } else {
          trackName = joinWithSeparator(joinWithSeparator(buildLanguageString(format),
              buildBitrateString(format)), buildTrackIdString(format));
        }
        return trackName.length() == 0 ? "unknown" : trackName;
      }

      private static String buildResolutionString(MediaFormat format) {
        return format.width == MediaFormat.NO_VALUE || format.height == MediaFormat.NO_VALUE
            ? "" : format.width + "x" + format.height;
      }

      private static String buildAudioPropertyString(MediaFormat format) {
        return format.channelCount == MediaFormat.NO_VALUE || format.sampleRate == MediaFormat.NO_VALUE
            ? "" : format.channelCount + "ch, " + format.sampleRate + "Hz";
      }

      private static String buildLanguageString(MediaFormat format) {
        return TextUtils.isEmpty(format.language) || "und".equals(format.language) ? ""
            : format.language;
      }

      private static String buildBitrateString(MediaFormat format) {
        String s=format.bitrate == MediaFormat.NO_VALUE ? ""
            : String.format(Locale.US, "%.2fMbit", format.bitrate / 1000000f);
     //   Toast.makeText(con, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return s;
      }

      private static String joinWithSeparator(String first, String second) {
        return first.length() == 0 ? second : (second.length() == 0 ? first : first + ", " + second);
      }

      private static String buildTrackIdString(MediaFormat format) {
        return format.trackId == null ? "" : " (" + format.trackId + ")";
      }

      private boolean onTrackItemClick(MenuItem item, int type) {
        if (player == null || item.getGroupId() != MENU_GROUP_TRACKS) {
          return false;
        }
        player.setSelectedTrack(type, item.getItemId() - ID_OFFSET);
        return true;
      }

      private void toggleControlsVisibility()  {                       /*///////////////////////////////////    Showing defalut controllers                  */
        if (mediaController.isShowing()) {
          mediaController.hide();
          debugRootView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
          showControls();
        }
      }


      private void showControls() {
        mediaController.show(0);
        debugRootView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }

      // DemoPlayer.CaptionListener implementation

      @Override
      public void onCues(List<Cue> cues) {
        subtitleLayout.setCues(cues);
      }

      // DemoPlayer.MetadataListener implementation

      @Override
      public void onId3Metadata(Map<String, Object> metadata) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : metadata.entrySet()) {
          if (TxxxMetadata.TYPE.equals(entry.getKey())) {
            TxxxMetadata txxxMetadata = (TxxxMetadata) entry.getValue();
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("ID3 TimedMetadata %s: description=%s, value=%s",
                TxxxMetadata.TYPE, txxxMetadata.description, txxxMetadata.value));
          } else if (PrivMetadata.TYPE.equals(entry.getKey())) {
            PrivMetadata privMetadata = (PrivMetadata) entry.getValue();
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("ID3 TimedMetadata %s: owner=%s",
                PrivMetadata.TYPE, privMetadata.owner));
          } else if (GeobMetadata.TYPE.equals(entry.getKey())) {
            GeobMetadata geobMetadata = (GeobMetadata) entry.getValue();
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("ID3 TimedMetadata %s: mimeType=%s, filename=%s, description=%s",
                GeobMetadata.TYPE, geobMetadata.mimeType, geobMetadata.filename,
                geobMetadata.description));
          } else {
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("ID3 TimedMetadata %s", entry.getKey()));
          }
        }
      }

      // SurfaceHolder.Callback implementation

      @Override
      public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (player != null) {
          player.setSurface(holder.getSurface());
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // Do nothing.
      }

      @Override
      public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (player != null) {
          player.blockingClearSurface();
        }
      }

      private void configureSubtitleView() {
        CaptionStyleCompat style;
        float fontScale;
        if (Util.SDK_INT >= 19) {
          style = getUserCaptionStyleV19();
          fontScale = getUserCaptionFontScaleV19();
        } else {
          style = CaptionStyleCompat.DEFAULT;
          fontScale = 1.0f;
        }
        subtitleLayout.setStyle(style);
        subtitleLayout.setFractionalTextSize(SubtitleLayout.DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE_FRACTION * fontScale);
      }

      @TargetApi(19)
      private float getUserCaptionFontScaleV19() {
        CaptioningManager captioningManager =
            (CaptioningManager) getSystemService(Context.CAPTIONING_SERVICE);
        return captioningManager.getFontScale();
      }

      @TargetApi(19)
      private CaptionStyleCompat getUserCaptionStyleV19() {
        CaptioningManager captioningManager =
            (CaptioningManager) getSystemService(Context.CAPTIONING_SERVICE);
        return CaptionStyleCompat.createFromCaptionStyle(captioningManager.getUserStyle());
      }

      /**
       * Makes a best guess to infer the type from a media {@link Uri} and an optional overriding file
       * extension.
       *
       * @param uri The {@link Uri} of the media.
       * @param fileExtension An overriding file extension.
       * @return The inferred type.
       */
      private static int inferContentType(Uri uri, String fileExtension) {
        String lastPathSegment = !TextUtils.isEmpty(fileExtension) ? "." + fileExtension
            : uri.getLastPathSegment();
        return Util.inferContentType(lastPathSegment);
      }

      private static final class KeyCompatibleMediaController extends MediaController {

        private MediaController.MediaPlayerControl playerControl;

        public KeyCompatibleMediaController(Context context) {
          super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void setMediaPlayer(MediaController.MediaPlayerControl playerControl) {
          super.setMediaPlayer(playerControl);
          this.playerControl = playerControl;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
          int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

          if (playerControl.canSeekForward() && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              playerControl.seekTo(playerControl.getCurrentPosition() + 15000); // milliseconds
              BandwidthMeter bm=player.getBandwidthMeter();
            Long l=bm.getBitrateEstimate();
            storeBitRate=l; 
            bitrateTextView.setText(storeBitRate+" bits/sec");
              show();
            }
            return true;
          } else if (playerControl.canSeekBackward() && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_REWIND) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              playerControl.seekTo(playerControl.getCurrentPosition() - 15000); // milliseconds
              show();
            }



            return true;
          }
          return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
      }
         private class LoadImages extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {

                    super.onPreExecute();
                    //pDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

                protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {

                    try {
                        vodImgThumb = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());
                        chImgLogo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[1]).getContent());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                        vodThumb.setImageBitmap(vodImgThumb);
                        chLogo.setImageBitmap(chImgLogo);                           

                }

            }
    }
```

`

Comment: i have checked this functionality with android MediaPlayer and its resuming the video from the last point it played before disconnecting the internet.

Comment: are you sure? Because in my experience with audio streams I have to detect the connectivity change and then resume the player (I actually restart the entire thing but in case of a live stream that's basically the same because the playhead is always 'now')

Comment: Thank God (and kotliners) we don't need to keep references of Views anymore with kotlin. Its too much boilerplate

Answer (score 3):

In demo of `ExoPlayer` this issue handle with retry button see how implemented [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v1/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/PlayerActivity.java).

First of all set an `ErrorListener` to determined some error happened then just call following piece of code fix the issue:

```
 if (playerNeedsPrepare) {
      player.prepare();
      playerNeedsPrepare = false;
      updateButtonVisibilities();
    }
    player.setSurface(surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
    player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
```

Answer (score 2):

playbackPreparer will be called when playButton clicked while **player.getPlaybackState() == Player.STATE_IDLE**

[PlayerControlView.java#L1111](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerControlView.java#L1111)

```
    playerView.setPlaybackPreparer {
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(
                ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(source).createMediaSource(video),
                false,
                true
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

ExoPlayer version 2.9 provides error handling customization via `LoadErrorHandlingPolicy`.

```
public final class CustomPolicy
    extends DefaultLoadErrorHandlingPolicy {

  @Override
  public long getRetryDelayMsFor(
      int dataType,
      long loadDurationMs,
      IOException exception,
      int errorCount) {
    // Replace NoConnectivityException with the corresponding
    // exception for the used DataSource.
    if (exception instanceof NoConnectivityException) {
      return 5000; // Retry every 5 seconds.
    } else {
      return C.TIME_UNSET; // Anything else is surfaced.
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int getMinimumLoadableRetryCount(int dataType) {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  }
}
```

More https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/load-error-handling-in-exoplayer-488ab6908137

Comment: How and where to use this CustomPolicy class

Comment: @MrinmoyMk Please follow this link for more info on usage https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/load-error-handling-in-exoplayer-488ab6908137

Comment: I have already seen this link. But it is given in the link about how and where to call the DefaultLoadErrorHandlingPolicy. Fortunately I am have successfully researched and implemented it.

Comment: This doesn't work for RTSP streams. If I reconnect the camera, the stream doesn't restart

Answer (score 1):

Create resume fun and do something like this:

```
player = [your exoPlayer]
fun resumeTrack() {
 if (player.playbackError != null) {
        player.retry();
    }
    setPlayWhenReady(true);
  exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like :

```
protected void play() {
    if (null != getPlaybackError()) {
        retry();
    }
    setPlayWhenReady(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `player.play()` in your `onClick()` method, just check if the player has a `sourceException` in `playerError` and call `player.prepare()` before calling `play()` like this in Kotlin:

```
player.playerError.takeIf { it?.sourceException is IOException }?.run {
     player.prepare()
}
```